# How can I pass a tag attribute on form submit?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a form and I want to get a datalist option attribute on submit. Do you have any idea to help me solve this problem. I created a similar scenario on stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/datalist-attr-problem

I can't use select because the list is very extensive, so it would be better using datalist.

I expect to log the chosen message id on console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to implement the autocomplete functionality. Unfortunately, `datalist` does not include any kind of `id` attribute for an `option`. It only gives a list of pre-defined options for an `input`. You could set an attribute on the options and use the value from the `input` to get the attribute value from the DOM, but it would be better to just get the value using JavaScript instead.

From the template, send the `input` reference instead of the `option` (This step is not required if you are using `ngModel` or `formControl`)

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="logMessageId(message)">
    <input class='form-control' list="equipment_name_list" name='equipment_name' #message>
    <datalist name="equipment_name_list" id="equipment_name_list">
        <option *ngFor="let message of messages" [value]="message.text"></option>
    </datalist>

    <button>Send</button>
</form>
```

Then in your component fetch the value from the list using [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```js
logMessageId(el){
    const message = el.value; // Use the ngModel or formControl value here instead if used
    const selectedMessage = this.messages.find(m => m.text === message);
    const messageId = (selectedMessage && selectedMessage.id) || message; // Use the message entered by the user if the not selected from the list
    console.log("Message Id: ", messageId);
}
```

You can also consider checking out Angular Material's [autocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples) component.

Comment: Thank you, bro! I tried to do something like this, but it doesn't work everytime. But I think this is the only solution using <datalist>, so I'll take a look on Angular Material's autocomplete!